# Changing background color of list view cell is not working at run time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with listview. First it loads all the item for the list successfully. Then I go to another screen from where I set a value for background color and save it locally. When I back to list view screen the background color of listview's row cell should be changed. But it remains same. When I restart the app only then it changes.

I am using converter to change the color at run time.

Please let me know if I am able to do it with converter or should I change it or make a property for the background color of row cell

Comment: Have you tried to assigned that updated value to your variable when screen appear again?(Using OnAppearing() method)?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar yes I am updating all the values in OnAppearing() method, all other properties are updating correctly. While updating I found that the color is changing in properties but its not reflecting on UI.

Comment: What is the binding source of color ? You can provide your code or share a sample which will be helpful to find the cause

Comment: Try to set ItemsSource of the list to null intentionally and then set it to your real collection e.g. MyListViewItems. It could trigger the ListView to reinitialize with new color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-binding and set the mode as `TwoWay`.

Using `{Binding Mode=TwoWay}`, if the user inputs a string that is a valid Hex format, the color will change.

### XAML

```xml
<ViewCell>
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" Orientation="Vertical">

        <Entry x:Name="entry" Text="{Binding Title ,Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black"/>

   </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

### Model

```cs
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string _title;
    public string Title 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _title; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (_title!= value)
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                TextColor = Color.FromHex(value);
            }
        } 
    }

    Color _textColor;
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _textColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_textColor != value)
            {
                _textColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```